# How do you create a direct Google Hangouts contact on the home screen?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, google-hangouts

This website described how to make a Hangouts contact. 
http://webcazine.com/9363/how-to-create-a-hangout-contact-shortcut-on-an-android-phone/

But it opens the contact in sms mode if Hangouts is also the default sms app.

Is there a way to create a direct Hangouts link that opens directly in Hangouts mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is now available as an option in Hangouts 7 which started rolling out in February 2016.**

To create a shortcut...

1. Open a Hangouts conversation.
2. Tap the 3-dot overflow menu in the top-right.
3. Tap "Save to Home Screen"

A conversation icon with will be placed on the home screen ready for quick access.  It works great!